# Regular Expression Help - Double checking answers

Tags: regex

I'm still a noob at Regular Expressions, but would anyone be so kind to double check to see if my answer is correct?

Question is: Indicate whether each of the given input strings belong to the language defined by the regex `(a | empty) b (a | b)* a (b)*`

Empty = flipped around 3 (empty string)

```
(a) input string: ababaa
Answer: Does not belong to the regex
because if tested, turns out to be ababab


(b) input string: aabbaa
Answer: Does not belong to the regex
Because if tested, turns out to be ab(b or a)* ab
```

are these answers correct?

Comment: is that first "A" meant to be capitalized? ie a different symbol from lowercase "a"?

Comment: whoops i'll edit it. its small a

Comment: seems like they should both match, unless (b)* means something other than "zero or more b's"

Comment: sorry is regex an actual program?
I'll edit it. its actyually only a regular expression

Comment: the confusion is: what does "turns out to be ababab" mean? it doesn't seem to be a meaningful statement in the context of regular expressions

Comment: to my knowledge (I dont have much knowledge) i think (b)* means more b's

Comment: well... (a or nothing), b, (a or b)*, a, (b)*

Comment: I think your knowledge is wrong ;) check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Basic_concepts

Comment: @Tuzki It helps to look at (a|b)* as `(a|b)(a|b)(a|b)`.... so on. (The pattern could occur 0 times as well.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second string does not belong to the language.  If you look at the regex, you can see that b must either be the first character (if (a|empty) selects empty), or must be the second character (if (a|empty) selects a).  Since the string starts with aa, it can't match.

The first string does match.  Just try to figure out each choice point so that you get the string provided.  It might help to work from the outside in, since (a|b)* is the most flexible part of the regex - i.e. you can match whatever you want to it.

Answer (score 0):

You can double check your answers by simply running them. Here's a site that does exactly that: http://regex.larsolavtorvik.com/